# Wordpress error when adding a parameter to the admin link

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm working on a plugin in the Wordpress admin. Everything works fine excepts that when I try to load the edit form; I get an error saying "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page".

My plugin link is:

```
http://localhost/work/wp/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-slider/index.php
```

The error appears when I append the ID parameter to the link like this:

```
http://localhost/work/wp/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-slider/index.php?id=5
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You url generated is wrong see double ? marks in your url.Your second argument must be with &.

The url must me like this

```
http://localhost/work/wp/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-slider/index.php&id=5
```